# True/False: $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: vector-spaces, definition

The answer is **False**.

Since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

However, can someone explicitly define the difference between a subset and subspace? I am somewhat struggling with the technicality of the following definition

Subspace: *a subspace, U of a vector space V, is a subset of V, $U \subset V$, such that U is a vector space in its own right, over the same field.*

Vector space: *A vector space over a field is a set $V$ of objects that is closed under binary operation ('addition') and scalar multiplication*

Also, what would make $\mathbb{R}^2$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ if anything?

Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb R^2 $ is $isomorphic$ to a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of things in $\Bbb{R}^3$ is $3$-component real vectors.  The set of thing in $\Bbb{R}^2$ is $2$-component real vectors.  (The component count is exactly what is being communicated by the "$n$" in $\Bbb{R}^n$.)  Since there are no $2$-component vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$, no element of $\Bbb{R}^2$ is in $\Bbb{R}^3$.  So $\Bbb{R}^2$ is not a subset, and hence not a subspace, of $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Yes! thank you, I believe this is what Don Thousand is conveying above as well

Comment: @Clark : Actually, \@DonThousand is going the other direction.  There is a natural copy of $\Bbb{R}^2$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$ where we set the "past 2" components to zero.  This generalizes.  There is a natural copy of $\Bbb{R}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^{10}$ where we set the past 2 components (the last eight components) to zero.  But being a copy is not the same as being the thing; this difference is captured by \@Nicolas's use of "isomorphic".

Answer (score 1):

When we say that $\mathbb R^2$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, we mean the canonical embedding of $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$, i.e., $(a,b)\mapsto(a,b,0)$ is a subspace.

It's not hard to show that this is true.

Comment: so is it simply because in $\mathbb{R}^2$ any vector contains two 'elements'?

Comment: @Clark Well, $\mathbb R^2$ represents a vector space of dimension $2$ over the reals, which means that it has two basis elements, so we can represent elements of this set as pairs of reals.

Comment: Yes, so since $\mathbb{R}^2$ only has 2 basis elements, it cannot be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which should have 3, right?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}^2$ is neither a subset nor a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Every subspace is also a subset and by definition, $\mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. In general, let $V$ be a vector space and $U$ be a subset of $V$. We say that $U$ is a subspace of $V$ if $U$ is also a vector space (so, in short, remember that a subspace is a subset of a larger vector space that is a vector space as well).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you ask, a "subset" of a vector space is a "subspace" if and only if it is "closed" under vector addition and scalar multiplication.  That is, if u and v are in the subset so is u+ v and av for any number a.

However, that is not really what you want to know!  R^2 is the set of vectors of the form (a, b) while R^3 nis the set of vectors of the form (a, b, c).  The first is not even a subset of the latter!  (There is an isomorphism from (a. b) to (a, b, 0) which IS a subspace of R^3.)

Answer (score -2):

Any set of elements $\in \mathbb R^3$ is by definition a subset of $\mathbb R^3$. A subspace is a particular subset which is a vector space, that is it is closed by multplication by scalars and by addition.

Therefore since we have that for any

$$\vec v\in \mathbb R^2 \implies \vec v \not \in \mathbb R^3 $$

then $\mathbb R^2$ can't be neither a subset nor a subspace of $\mathbb R^3 $.

What is true is that any plane through the origin is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.